# Apply numerical filters with DM script functions

Tags: imagefilter, dm-script

Are there DM script functions that will allow direct access to the numerical filters found under the "Spectrum/Numerical Filters" menu such as:

- Savitzky-Golay

  and the others: Smooth (low-pass), Structure (high-pass), First
  derivative, Log derivative, Log-log derivative, and Second Derivative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are such commands, but these are not officially documented/supported and may be used with caution. They may not exist/work in all versions of the software.

```
RealImage Smooth_Spectrum( RealImage, Number )
RealImage Structure_Spectrum( RealImage, Number )
RealImage FDeriv_Spectrum( RealImage, Number, Number, Number )
RealImage SDeriv_Spectrum( RealImage, Number, Number, Number, Number )
RealImage LogDeriv_Spectrum( RealImage, Number, Number, Number )
RealImage LogLogDeriv_Spectrum( RealImage, Number, Number, Number, Number, Number )
RealImage SavitzkyGolay_Filter( RealImage, Number, Number, Number, Number )
```

[image: Menu]

Comment: I am having hard time in figuring out the arguments in this "SavitzkyGolay_Filter" function - getting the "bad args in savgol" error message often. Is there some brief instruction what are these 4 number arguments means?

Comment: @KEVIVI The four parameters in order (all interpreted as unsigned intergers) should be "Channels Left", "Channels Right", "derivative Order", "Polynomial Order".  The smoothing width is [lCh+rCh+1]. If derivative Order = 0, you only get smoothing...

Comment: Using the menu command with the setting ("5 channels width" and "4th order") is equivalent to calling with the parameters: (5,5,0,4)